# Message=Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: error

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

HI Guys,
I have created a web service. And I m able to hit the web service using SOAPUI but when i try to call through my code I get this error.
Any ideas?

ok the web service code looks like this:

```
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name = "SoapBinding", Namespace = "xyz")]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[WebService(Namespace = "http://Search")]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Stub : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public Stub()
    {
        Log.Debug(this,string.Format("this is just a test message"));
    }


    [WebMethod]
    public Response searchAsset(Request serviceTag)
    {
    }
```

And my client code is:

```
Search _search = new Search();
_search.url;
_search.n.wcred;
_search.searchAsset(request);
```

Comment: You forgot to show your code (preferably the client **and** the service).

Comment: I got it resolved.
Actually the function which i was mocking in wsdl had some more parameters which I forgot to use. And after I added  it started working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solved my problem with the SoapAction:

```
[SoapDocumentService(RoutingStyle = SoapServiceRoutingStyle.RequestElement)]
```

[SoapServiceRoutingStyle Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapserviceroutingstyle.aspx)
SoapAction  The SOAP message is routed based on the SOAPAction HTTP header.
RequestElement  The SOAP Message is routed based on the first child element following the  XML element of the SOAP message.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause I've heard of this is that the value in whatever the real code of:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://Search")]
```

If this value isn't what the server expects, the error message you report will happen.